# liquibase gradle postgresql wrong driver

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, gradle, liquibase

### Environment:

- Spring boot (STS 3.9.1)
- Gradle 2.13
- Postgresql 9.6.5
- Liquibase Gradle plugin (liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.4)

### Scenario:

We have a spring boot rest api, we want it to have a CI process that updates the database at a stage of the process, for this we want to use gradle for it

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE')
// tag::build[]
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
// end::build[]
        classpath('org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.4')
        classpath('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
// tag::plugin[]
apply plugin: 'docker'
// end::plugin[]
apply plugin: 'org.liquibase.gradle'

bootRun {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', System.properties['spring.profiles.active']
}


def changeLog = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.yaml"

task('dev') << {
println 'executing dev'
liquibase{
    activities {
        main {
        changeLogFile changeLog
        url 'postgresql://localhost/mydatabase'
        username 'postgres'
        password 'mysecret'
        driver 'org.postgresql.Driver'
        }
    }
}
}

jar {
    baseName = 'applicationTestLiquibasegradle'
    version =  '0.0.3'
}

// This is used as the docker image prefix (org)
group = 'com.cropmetrics'
version = '0.0.3'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

// tag::task[]
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
  applicationName = jar.baseName
  dockerfile = file('Dockerfile')
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from jar
      into "${stageDir}/target"
    }
  }
}
// end::task[]


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
  compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
  // JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...)
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

  compile('org.liquibase:liquibase-core')
  compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4.jre7')
  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

So we have a dev task created in order to execute this:

```
gradle task dev update
```

Which should update the database

It works great if we allow the app to update the database automatically, but if we want to use the taskt plugin and use gradle tasks we are getting the error

```
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':update'.
> liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to postgresql://localhost/cropmetricsdatabase with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

So the problem seems to be related to the liquibase-gradle plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Your db url looks kinda strange. Missing jdbc part and probably port number.

From [documentation](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc): the driver recognises JDBC URLs of the form:

```
jdbc:postgresql:database
jdbc:postgresql:/
jdbc:postgresql://host/database
jdbc:postgresql://host/
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/
```

Comment: I changed it to `url 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cropmetricsdatabase' ` and I get another error

`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':update'.
> liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml`

Comment: and this is the stack trace
`SEVERE 10/25/17 6:12 AM: liquibase: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml
 at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:23)
 at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:227)
 at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
 at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
 at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1096)
 at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:180)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0`

Comment: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/yaml_format.html To use YAML-based changelogs, you must include snakeyaml-1.12.jar in your classpath

Comment: I have this path on STS, $(pwd)/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/7a27ea250c5130b2922b86dea63cbb1cc10a660c/snakeyaml-1.17.jar